# Trim all images in a folder

Tags: c#, image

i have a folder filled with png files, that are transparent around the edges.
How can i automaticly trim or crop thoes files.
With a program or a C# Script?

Comment: Please add what you tried so far

Comment: Paint.NET might do the trick, I doubt you could do them in batch though.

Comment: I've just tried a buch of c# scripts. But they didn't do the trick.

Plain.Net will check that out - now!

Answer (score 4):

Check out ImageMagick and Mogrify: http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html

Comment: Thanks! Cant get it to work though, dont think it support 64bit windows :(

Answer (score 2):

For late googlers, Matthews recommendation of image magick is perfect, an example would be typing:

```
mogrify -trim *.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading a Mouse Recorder :) Then i could just use Photoshops to trim one image, and repeat the mouse movement to do it on all 600 images. It's done now.